# Maven resource filtering not replacing property

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

Here's my properties file:

```
version = ${maven.build.timestamp}
```

Here's how my pom.xml file looks like:

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
    ...
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

And here's how my directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── resources
│       │   └── application.properties
```

But when I do a `mvn clean install` and open up the `target/classes/application.properties` file, the contents of it is still the same: `version = ${maven.build.timestamp}`

Why isn't the property being properly replaced?

Comment: You can just put src/main/resources by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue in Maven ([see here](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-603)).
Simplest workaround is to redefine this property in your POM:

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</maven.build.timestamp>
</properties>
```

Although this could generate an error in IDE like Eclpise it's still working as a maven build. Alternatively you could redefine this property with your own name to avoid IDE warnings.